# Ramda: Duplicate an object by its (array) property

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, ramda.js

I have an object that has an array property `{ property: [a, b] }`, and I want to have a list of duplicated objects where `[{ property: [a] }, { property: [b] }]`

The input is:

```
const input = {
  url: 'getting-started',
  locales: ['en-GB', 'en-JP']
}
```

Expected form is:

```
const expected = [{
  url: 'getting-started',
  locales: ['en-GB']
}, {
  url: 'getting-started',
  locales: ['en-JP']
}]
```

The function I wrote is a bit unreadable, and not even pure:

```
const duplicateByLocales = article => R.pipe(
  R.prop('locales'),
  R.invert,
  R.mapObjIndexed((val, locale) =>
    R.pipe(
      R.clone,
      R.assoc('locales', R.of(locale))
    )(article)),
  R.values
)(article)
```

It does work, but I'm curious about what a better way could look like? Thank you!

Comment: I've edited your question to fix the code formatting. For future reference, SO doesn't use the usual markdown conventions for formatting: code blocks are marked as such by indenting everything 4 spaces (I know, it's weiird). You can also highlight the code block and hit ctrl-k (cmd-k on mac) and it will do it for you.

Comment: Why does the output have `locales: ['en-GB']` rather than `locale: 'en-GB'`?

Comment: @ScottSauyet You're right, it should be `locale: 'en-GB'`! An oversight on my end

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```js
const input = {
  url: 'getting-started',
  locales: ['en-GB', 'en-JP']
}

let result = input.locales.map(locale => ({...input, locales:[locale]}));
console.log(result);
```

Keep in mind that `{...input}` creates a shallow copy of `input`. If `input` has multiple levels, this gets a bit more complex.

And we can write a function for it

```js
const transform = input =>
  input.locales.map(locale => ({...input, locales:[locale]}))

console.log(transform({
  url: 'getting-started',
  locales: ['en-GB', 'en-JP']
}))
```

Comment: Nice, I never would have thought of overwriting the key like that after the spread. Surprised this doesn't throw in strict mode, but apparently not (just tried it in chrome in a strict mode IIFE).

Comment: Thank you this is definitely an improvement, but I was trying to find out a pure way of doing it, your function refers to external context (with `...input`). So I think ideally the function would take the object, and return an array.

Comment: This is not a function but an expression.  Converting it to a function, via something like `const tranform = input => input.locales.map(...)` we do get a pure function.

Comment: If you'd prefer `locale: 'en-JP'` rather than `locales: ['en-JP']` in the resulting list of objects, you can tweak the `transform` function in the answer slightly like so: `({locales, ...rest}) => locales.map(locale => ({locale, ...rest}))`